# using property value in @Query Annotation /@repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

i need your help!

is there any way of using property value in @Query Annotation ?
see below code example

`@Repository
public interface SomeRep extends CrudRepository<MyClass, Long> {

@Transactional
@Query(value = "{call sp_name(:param1, :param2, :param3, :param4)}", nativeQuery = true)
List spErrorCall(String param1, String param2, Integer param3, Integer param4);`

I want to use sp_name as a variable from application.properties...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
    @Query(
    value = "call ${#environment['sp.name']}(:param1, :param2, :param3, :param4)",
 nativeQuery = true
    )
    List spErrorCall(String param1, String param2, Integer param3, Integer param4);
```

Then, in application.properties file, you need to specify your function name:

> sp.name=...

You can check more info here: https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions